# Prevent MS SQL 2005 master DB from being corrupted

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to resolve what cause the following corruption.

> 2011-06-29 10:47:26.42 spid5s      Starting up database 'master'.
>
> 2011-06-29 10:47:26.53 spid5s      Error: 9003, Severity: 20, State: 1.
>
> 2011-06-29 10:47:26.53 spid5s      The log scan number (216:72:1) passed to log scan in database 'master' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup.
>
> 2011-06-29 10:47:26.53 spid5s Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.

I can find plenty of threads and information on how to recover databases when master db is corrupt. I can recover them succussfully.

HOWEVER, this is not very satisfactory for customers to have perform these operations. I have been able to examine event log files of when the corruption occurs. From there I can see server working fine then computer is shutdown, few hours later the computer is switched on and master db is corrupted.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of:

- disk corruption. Run chkdsk etc with SQL Server shutdonw
- someone has been playing with the MDF/LDF files

The master DB starts once when SQL Server starts up: so why did this happen? Patch? BSOD? PEBKAC? Note: the MDF/LDF files won't be locked when SQL is shutdown...

I can't recall a corrupt master, ever, unless it's one of the 3 reasons above

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. On one of the occasions that this occurred I performed a chkdsk, no errors. Unfortunately, I cannot always run this check as it takes time on the end users machine.

I don't believe end users would play with mdf/ldf intentionally, but something maybe in conflict with them. Anti-virus?

PEBKAC - I cannot control end users, so I need to prevent this.

Comment: @leon: Some AV solutions will try to scan the MDF/LDF files: they should be excluded. As for users, you have no chance of preventing file changes unless you can secure the files.

Comment: there are sooooOO many different AV how can I exclude it on all end users' pcs for all different pcs?

Comment: @leon: you can't know. And secure the files means NTFS security which can be changed by users of course. So you're screwed. This is why SQL Server should run a network server. For a local app, consider SQL Server CE or SQLite